# Borel measurability of a set

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

Hey guys I have a question on the Borel measurability of this set $\{{(x,y):x∈E,0<y<f(x)}\}$ when $f$ is a continuous function defined in an open set. Can anyone help me out? I think the set is open, but I'm a bit confused with the proof. Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Just to check: $E$ is an open set, and $f:E\rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ is continuous on $E$, and you want to know if the strict hypograph $\mbox{hyp}(f):=\{(x,y):x\in E \mbox{ and } 0<y<f(x)\}$ is Borel measurable?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: So, for any point $x\in E$ there is a corresponding set $E_x = \{y: 0<y<f(x)\}$ and so $\mbox{hyp}(f) = \cup_{x\in E} E_x$.  Does that help you at all?

Comment: So this $E_x$ is going to be an open set and when we make the union it is also open so its borel mensurable?

Comment: Yes, though Jordan Green's answer is also a good way to look at it.  You'll use both approaches (finding pre-images and creating specific sets to union or intersect) as you study further

Comment: Alright , Thanks man!!

Comment: Just a quick question that got me confused now, where did we use the fact that the functions was continuous , was it to say that $hyp(f)=\bigcup E_{x}$?

Comment: No, it's to ensure that each $E_x$ is a measurable set.  For Lebesgue and Borel measures all continuous functions are measurable

Comment: im not really seeing how the continuity ensures that $E_x$ is measurable....

Comment: So, since $f$ is continuous, it's measurable, and so the sets $\{x | f(x)>\alpha \}$ and $\{x | f(x) < \alpha \}$ (and those with inequality signs instead) are all measurable.  The sets $E_x$ can be written $E_x = \{ y | f(y)\geq 0\} \cap \{y | f(y) < f(x) \}$

Comment: ah yeah but thats the thing i was asking, ur using the fact that its measurable because its continous , see my teacher defined that a function is measurable iff $hyp(f)$ is measurable , thats why im trying to prove it just using the fact that its continuous.

Comment: Ok, but that's never stated in your question, so I can't really apologise for not knowing that :)  Use Jordan's answer -- that doesn't require any circularity in this case.

Comment: Yeah no problem man, i was just confused (:, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instinct that the hypograph is open is correct.  To see this, define $F: E \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $F(x,y) = f(x) - y$.  Since $f$ is continuous, so is $F$.  Your set is the pre-image of $(0, \infty)$ and is therefore open.